# TypeError: Unable to set property 'props' of undefined or null reference - react native component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new in react native. as i checked my code is fine where i am learning from about component but still getting error for props even in documentation react native using props component as i am using but why still getting error check document link (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props)

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

    class UserInformation extends Component(){
      render(){
        return(
          <View>
            <Text>{this.props.Name}</Text>
            <Text>{this.props.Status}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }

}

function App() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

       <UserInformation Name='Hamza' Status='Single' />
       <UserInformation Name='Shahwar' Status='Comitted' />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Error: TypeError: Unable to set property 'props' of undefined or null reference**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `extend` a functional component. Instead seems to me it is a typo error here:

```
class UserInformation extends Component{
                            //--------^^-------remove ()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Class Component you need to change

`class UserInformation extends Component(){`

to

`class UserInformation extends React.Component{`

and add

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props) // <---- this is the part which give you this.props
}
```

But ... I suggest you use function component like App()

```
const UserInformation = (props) => {
        return(
          <View>
            <Text>{props.Name}</Text>
            <Text>{props.Status}</Text>
          </View>
        );
}
```

Comment: If you're using Class Component you can use Component because above example using Component import.                                                                                                           import React, {Component} from 'react';